# Dc.js with React: how to make a grouped bar chart?

Tags: reactjs, dc.js, crossfilter

Reference to this link https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/tcraqj5e/6/
Can someone help me create a grouped bar chart using **react-dc-js**?
I was able to create a dimension and group like in this link, however, unable to figure out as to how to use the following parts in the code:

```
 group={() => {
         return [
          speedSumGroup,
                "1",
                sel_stack("1"),
              ];
            }}

  for (var i = 2; i < 6; ++i) {
        chart.stack(speedSumGroup, "" + i, sel_stack(i));
    }
```

Here is a Fiddle I tried. I am unable to add react-dc-js to the fiddle however has the structure of code I am using.

https://jsfiddle.net/Physicalpixel/nmL04b5z/97/

Comment: Just confirming, I don't think it's supported. It might make more sense to open an issue on [the repo](https://github.com/dc-js/react-dc-js).